# Make foreign key as a primary key in model

Tags: java, hibernate, model, primary-key

I need to make a foreign key column as a primary key in my hibernate application model. when i set @Id there is an error. 
this is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "otp")
public class OTP {
@Id
private Origin origin;
private int code;
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = true)
private Date created_at=new Date();
}
```

Above entity model cannot add the id. So how to add the id for a foreign key column. As you see i have origin class one to one relationship. I need that relationship to be primary key

Comment: Does it work, if you add a OneToOne? I'm not 100% sure, how to handle it, but it might also be doable with a combination of EmbeddedId and MapsId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys allow duplicates, which make them unsuitable as Primary Keys most of the time. However this is not a rule.

The only exception to this are tables with a one-to-one relationship, where the foreign key and primary key of the linked table are the same.

I came across similar scenario and did something like this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_DETAILS")
public class PersonDetails {
    @Id
    private Long personId; 

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON", nullable = false)
    @MapsId
    private Person person;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_PRSN_ID", sequenceName = "SQ_PRSN_ID")
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SQ_PRSN_ID", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID_PERSON", nullable = false)
    private Long personId;
    ...
}
```

I found similar example [here](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapsId), hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot make a relationship as Primary key. Instead you can make the foreign key as a primary key, if and only if the relationship between the two tables is one-to-one.

Here in your case, as it is one-to-one we are good to go.

But instead of annotating Origin with @Id. Annotate the foreign key with @Id and use  @MapsId while you define relationship.

Refer example code below where Person and Person Details has one-to-one relationship.

**Person Details entity looks like:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_details")
public class PersonDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_details_Id")
    private Long personId;

     @Column(name = "person_name")
    private String personName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_Id")
    @MapsId
    private Person person;

    ...
}
```

**Person entity looks like:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq")
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Long personId;

    @Column(name = "person_profsn")
    private String personProfession;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
    private PersonDetails personDetails;

    ...
}
```